# What does the go.work.sum file track in Go 1.18?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-work

I just tried out the [Go 1.18 workspace](https://go.dev/ref/mod#workspaces) on an existing project. Consider the following project directory structure:

```
project-root/
|-- app/
|  |-- go.mod
|  |-- go.sum
```

[Per documentation](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/workspaces), I ran the command `go work init ./app` within the root directory of the project. This command created a `go.work` file as expected, but it also created a `go.work.sum` file that was not expected.

What's confusing is that `go.work.sum` references two modules that can be found in `go.sum`, but the version of each module is not the same when compared between `go.sum` and `go.work.sum`. Then there is also the question why are only these two modules referenced in `go.work.sum` but none of the other ones? Note that there is only  the one module within the workspace.

What does the `go.work.sum` file track? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `go.work.sum` file is mentioned in the related feature proposal (and seemingly nowhere else?):

https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/45713-workspace.md#files

> The go command will use the collective set of `go.sum` files that exist across the workspace modules to verify dependency modules, but there are cases where the `go.sum` files in the workspace modules collectively do not contain all sums needed to verify the build: The simpler case is if the workspace `go.mod` files themselves are incomplete, **the go command will add missing sums to the workspace‘s `go.work.sum` file rather than to the module’s `go.sum`.**

The proposal (same link as above) also describes one more use case where neither of the individual projects import packages from some particular version of a module, but require it as indirect dependency, thus missing the checksum for the module's code.

So your sub-modules may show one of these situations. If it's the former, I'd expect running `go mod tidy` on the sub-modules puts everything in sync and removes the need for `go.work.sum`. Based on your description, it sounds like it's the latter instead, then `go.work.sum` is necessary to track the missing checksums.

Comment: I have created an issue in the Go repo to transfer the documentation on go.work.sum from the proposal to the official docs: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/51941